# PHP Date: get every Friday at specific hour

Tags: php, date

I've tried looking for different similar answers but couldn't find any.

(Note: While writing this is Thu, 02 Nov 2017 23:51:42)

I need a function to show the date of the next (closest) Friday at 2pm.

I came up to this:

```
return date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime( "next friday 2pm"));
```

The result is `1510318800` which translated to a date is `Fri, 10 Nov 2017 13:00:00 GMT` instead of showing the 03 Nov. Also the time is wrong.

How do I get the function to show the closest Friday at 2pm?

Comment: At `02-11-2017 23:55:00` that code gave me `03-11-2017 14:00:00` So I guess you are in a non UTC Timezone

Comment: What is your server timezone set too? You can find by  `echo date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: I'm currently in Aruba but the server is in Italy, so the Italian time is used. Currently is `03-11-2017 00:59:00` but still, I should get the hours correct, it should go to 2pm

Comment: @Randall "Europe/Rome"

Comment: I dont believe the duplicate mark is accurate, as the odd behavior is DUE to strtotime, which that answer does not cover.

Comment: Its doing what you ask. Next Friday is the 10th. Drop the next. return date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime( "friday 2pm"));

Comment: @miknik yeeeeahhhh!!!! Ok what if today is Friday 3pm, does it show 1 hour ago time or the next coming friday?

Comment: It will give you the same day, even if the hour is passed. Because its picking the first friday it finds (today), regardless of the time. Same issue as if telling it next friday, regardless of time. This is why mixing both needs, just isn't going to work with strtotime :(

Comment: Its not going to take much to make it work. $dateinfuture = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime( "friday 12:30am"));
$now = new DateTime("now");
if ($now > $dateinfuture) {
    $dateinfuture = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime( "next friday 12:30am"));
}

Comment: I tested this for your need and it seems to work solid: `$now = time(); for($n = 0; $n < 8; $n++) { $test = mktime(14,00,00,date('m'),date('d')+$n,date('Y')); if ($test > $now and date('D',$test) == 'Fri') { $closest = $test; break; } } echo $closest;` ... you can change `$now = mktime(12,00,00,11,3,2017);` to test different compares. Probably can be reduced some more.

Comment: Actually I think I like @miknik example better. Shorter.

Comment: Does anybody want to answer the question so I can accept it? @miknik

Comment: Its been marked as a duplicate, so nobody can answer. Thanks anyway!